# How to add user-specific (private) Data to Mongo-DB Model

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, database-design, nosql

Say I have an `Song` Schema:

```
{
 title: 'Perfect Day',
 artist: 'Lou Reed',
 lyrics: [ {text: 'Oh such a perfect day', ... }, {text: 'I wish I spent it with you', ... } ... ] //all the lines go here
 //....
}
```

This song item will be the same for all users. This document might not just have embedded data, but also references (e.g. the lyrics might be stored in a separate lyrics collection at some point).

**Problem**

I want users to be able to make notes, highlight lines, comment on lyrics: not publicly, but just on *their own* document.

So I cannot really modify this base document, which has to remain 'clean' & the same for all users. And I guess copying the whole document and modifying it would be a bad idea, since then I'll have duplicate data and potentially *a lot* of that.

How would I solve something like this in mongodb?

Comment: Think about having a `songs` field which is an array of _song_ objects - for a _user_; e.g., `songs: [ { id: ObjectId, notes: "Like it...", highlights: { ... } },  { ... } ]`. Each song object can have reference to the `songs` document with the `ObjectId`.